# django runserver shows too many logs

Tags: django, logging, django-haystack

For instance, when django haystack gets more_like_this data, the console is flooded with the result data.

How can I suppress specific log? for example django-haystack related log?

```
def more_like_this(self):
    from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

    sqs = SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(self).models(type(self)).exclude(id=self.id).exclude(deleted=True)
    sqs.load_all()

    return sqs # generates tons of log...
```

Comment: it's spitting loggs for 3 seconds.. I can't afford such a big screen sadly;;

Comment: Much improved with code. Still, your problem doesn't sound all that specific. How would we random people of the internet know how you want to filter that log data? Is it ironic that it's called haystack?

Comment: maybe I can turn off runserver's logging of `return statement` or a specific view? or specific app(haystack) ..